# Select MAX INT value of TEXT column

Tags: sql, oledb, ms-access-2010

```
UserID    UserName  Password

1                abc               123
10               xyz               456
3                mno               254

SELECT MAX(UserId) AS UserId FROM UserLogin
```

When I run this query it gives me 3 instead of 10

All columns are TEXT datatype

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your query is returning `3` because it is the largest value considering lexicographic order (anything starting with `3` is considered greater than anything starting with `1`, just like something starting with `b` is greater than anything starting with `a`).

Use the [`VAL`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/val-function-HA001228931.aspx) function to convert the TEXT columns into numeric values:

```
SELECT MAX(VAL(UserId)) AS UserId FROM UserLogin
```

If you're concerned about performance, you should make this column numeric, though. Take into account you're calling a function for every row in the table. Also, it won't be using any indexes this column may have.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the column type is numeric and not varchar or string.

Comment: all coloumns are TEXT datatype. i havent use autonumber for userID

Comment: That's why, then.  I wouldn't consider that a very good implementation of anything.

Comment: Xavi López gives me best answer rather than yours

Comment: He's encouraging you to do something that 'works', but may not be in your best interest in the long run.  You'd be better served by modeling your problem correctly in the database.

Comment: @Means duffy is addressing the real issue here. What I provided is a workaround and you should really consider changing your data model.

Comment: i cant change database even i know primary key have int datatype but some situation..

Comment: that's fine.  maybe the next person who comes along will benefit from knowing that modeling ints as strings has consequences that matter.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change

```
SELECT MAX(val(UserId)) AS UserId FROM UserLogin
```