# How to select the max int value of a TEXT column in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Given a TABLE `mytable` with a column of TEXT `name` containing VALUES `1, 2, 2b, 2c, 3`. How do you select the maximum INT value in SQLite?

```
-- Does not work in SQLite
SELECT MAX(VAL(textcol)) FROM mytable;
```

Took me some time to find as I kept falling on instructions for [other SQL syntaxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355592/select-max-int-value-of-text-column).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(name AS INT)) FROM mytable;
```

SQLite uses CAST(expr AS type-name) similar to [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496874/how-to-select-max-of-mixed-string-int-column)